# can not format date properly when using date.js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Iam trying to convert the format of date from dd-MM-yyyy into yyyy-MM-dd using date.js java script libray ..
for that I used following code

```
var myDate = Date.parse("15-09-2014");
DateFormat = myDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
alert(DateFormat );
```

so when alerting `DateFormat` i got the correct output as 2014-09-15 . But when i am trying to format a date in which the day is below 13 , i got the output in which the day and date positions interchanged...
for example when i give input as "12-09-2014", i got the result as 2014-12-09....but am expecting 2014-09-12...
Can anybody help me please...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseExact` to define your format.

```
var myDate = Date.parseExact("11-09-2014", "d-M-yyyy");
DateFormat = myDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
alert(DateFormat);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mf4v6wjd/1/